# update a link after user chooses autocomplete sugggestion

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im using jquery ui autocomplete with google map api (http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/) to prompt locations to users as they type. After a user selects one of the suggestions, I want to update a link on the page. I'm doing this:

```
$.widget( "ui.geo_autocomplete", {

// setup the element as an autocomplete widget with some geo goodness added
_init: function() {
    this.options._geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder; // geocoder object
    this.options._cache = {}; // cache of geocoder responses
    this.element.autocomplete(this.options);


    // _renderItem is used to prevent the widget framework from escaping the HTML required to show the static map thumbnail
    this.element.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(_ul, _item) {
        return $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', _item).append(this.options.getItemHTML(_item)).appendTo(_ul);
    };
},

// default values
options: {

            change: function() {  
                 //change the link
            },
```

The problem is that the change function is only executed after the user chooses a suggestion, and then clicks somewhere else on the page. If they choose a suggestion, then immediately click on link, it has not been updated. How can I update the link immediately after a user chooses one of the prompted suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `select` event instead. See the [official documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#events) for event documentation.